# Logging in production and proguard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have LOG.d everywhere in my code. When it comes to production/releasing, is this debugs off by default ? Or should I surround them conditional phrases.

Also if Proguard removes the debug statements, then the crash reports I will get will have incorrect line numbers, right?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log messages are still visible in release mode, proguard doesn't touch those.

The "debug" in Log.d is the level of log message.

Proguard obfuscates the file names and source lines so on stack traces you wont see them, but you can map back to the original source or configure proguard to keep those.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Comment: You can get proguard to retain the line numbers by adding the following to you progaurd.cfg file. `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable`